# Git repository workspace folder not displayed in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I have a project in Eclipse that is not navigable in Finder. All the other projects within the same Git repository are fine and can be browsed with Finder.

[image]

This image should be displaying an Eclipse project folder, *not* what it is displaying currently. What's even more curious is that it shows a very old modified date. I have modified this project as of today August 27, 2013. The project runs and compiles fine, but is curiously messed up in Finder.

As stated earlier, all other repo project folders appear to be fine. Am I using an illegal/reserved word? Please advise.

**The folder is navigable via Terminal, just not in Finder.**

It also appears to be from the usage of `.service` in the project folder name. Since Git will not allow me to rename, I am looking for a way to get around this in Finder.

**Edit**

I have been able to confirm that the name is causing the problem.  Now how to rename via git in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're right when you say that the problem comes from the .service extension of your folder.

To browse your project from Finder, you can right-click on the folder and click on "Display Bundle Contents", right under "Open".